# Python Issue using request and post to login to website before scraping data

Tags: python, post, authentication, request, screen-scraping

I am trying to login to a website using 'request and post' before I scrape some data.
The login does not seem to work, as in, the data I get before and after I login does not differ. However if I manually login using my browser the data before and after login is different, for example I can see my profile on the main page. I have also put the login in a try-except format to see if it's showing any exceptions, but with no luck.
I have checked and made sure I am inputting all the 'form data' requested by login on the page.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

My code is below:

```
import urllib
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

POST_LOGIN_URL = 'https://wex.nz/login'
REQUEST_URL = 'https://wex.nz'

payload = {'email':'testemail@gmail.com','password':'testpassword'}

with requests.Session() as session:
    try:
        post = session.post(POST_LOGIN_URL, data=payload, headers={"Referer":"https://wex.nz"})
    except:
        print('login failed')


    r = session.get(REQUEST_URL)
    page_html= r.content
    page_soup= soup(page_html, "html.parser")

    profile_container=page_soup.findAll("div",{"class":"profile"})

    print(profile_container)
```

Comment: Try to log in with your browser after opening the network inspector. You'll notice that the form posts additional data to "email" and "password". Namely "captchaInput", "csrfToken", "otp" and "PoW_nonce".

Comment: In addition, you should browse to the home page with the "session" before posting the credentials, in order to get the cookies.